Unable to connect Keycloak container and Paperless NGX container using Traefik
I want to connect the Paperless NGX server with Keycloak Authentication both of which are in the same network and served behind Traefik reverse proxy. These are the respective compose files
Paperless NGX
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

services:
  broker:
    # ... some config

  db:
    # ... some config

  paperless:
    image: ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - proxy
      - default
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.paperless.rule: Host(`paperless.localhost`)
      traefik.http.routers.paperless.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.services.paperless.loadbalancer.server.port: 8000
      traefik.docker.network: proxy
      traefik.http.routers.paperless.tls: true
    depends_on:
      - db
      - broker
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/usr/src/paperless/data
      - ./media:/usr/src/paperless/media
      - ./export:/usr/src/paperless/export
      - ./consume:/usr/src/paperless/consume
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      PAPERLESS_REDIS: redis://broker:6379
      PAPERLESS_DBHOST: db
      PAPERLESS_TIKA_ENABLED: 1
      PAPERLESS_TIKA_GOTENBERG_ENDPOINT: http://gotenberg:3000
      PAPERLESS_TIKA_ENDPOINT: http://tika:9998
      PAPERLESS_EMAIL_HOST: mailhog
      PAPERLESS_EMAIL_PORT: 1025
      PAPERLESS_EMAIL_HOST_USER: 'Document Archive'
      PAPERLESS_EMAIL_USE_TLS: true
      PAPERLESS_APPS: 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid_connect'
      PAPERLESS_SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS: '{"openid_connect": {"APPS": [{"provider_id": "keycloak","name": "Employee Login","client_id": "${CLIENT_ID}","secret": "${CLIENT_SECRET}","settings": { "server_url": "https://keycloak.localhost/realms/${REALM}/.well-known/openid-configuration", "oauth_pkce_enabled": true, "token_auth_method": "client_secret_basic"}}]}}'
      PAPERLESS_DEBUG: "YES" # TODO: Set to "NO" in production
      PAPERLESS_URL: "https://paperless.localhost"
  gotenberg:
    # ... some config
  
  tika:
   # ... some config

Keycloak
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

services:
  keycloak:
    networks:
      - default
      - proxy
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule: Host(`keycloak.localhost`)
      traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port: 8080
      traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.docker.network: proxy
      traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls: true
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      KC_DB: ${KC_DB}
      KC_DB_URL: ${KC_DB_URL}
      KC_DB_USER: ${KC_DB_USER}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${KC_DB_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_WELCOME_THEME: ${KEYCLOAK_WELCOME_THEME}
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_PROXY_PROTOCOL_ENABLED: true
      KC_PROXY_HEADERS: xforwarded
    develop:
      watch:
        - path: docker-compose.yml
          action: rebuild
        - path: themes
          action: sync
          target: /opt/keycloak/themes
    # command: ['start', '--optimized', '--features=preview']
    command: ['start-dev', '--features=preview']
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
      mailhog:
        condition: service_started
        restart: true
  db:
    # ... some config

  mailhog:
    # ... some config

Traefik
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
services:
  traefik:
    networks:
      - proxy
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --providers.file.directory=/etc/traefik/dynamic
    
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule: Host(`traefik.localhost`)
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.service: api@internal
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls: true
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8081:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./certs:/etc/certs/
      - ./certs-traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/dynamic/certs-traefik.yml

The problem is when I try to authenticate the user from Paperless-NGX to Keycloak the Keycloak server responds with the following error message.
Invalid token issuer. Expected 'http://keycloak:8080/realms/<REALM>'

Also, the client redirects to keycloak:8080 instead of keycloak.localhost
I have no idea what is wrong, my guess is that the service redirects to the inner container name resolution since both the containers are in the same network, but I am unsure how the traefik redirection would work in the host.
Please help! Thank you for any answers in advance.
